# SAXParseException error in XML Parsing

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Using web service call ,I got the following response from server. Now i need to parse this response, Extract all field values and store it in String values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ecomexpress-objects version="1.0"><object pk="1" model="awb">
    <field type="BigIntegerField" name="awb_number">102019265</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="orderid">8008444</field>
    <field type="FloatField" name="actual_weight">2</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="origin">DELHI-DSW</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="destination">Mumbai - BOW</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="current_location_name">Mumbai - BOW</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="current_location_code">BOW</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="customer">Ecom Express Private Limited - 32012</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="consignee">BEECHAND VERMA</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="pickupdate">22-Jan-2014</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="status">Undelivered</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="tracking_status">Undelivered</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="reason_code">221 - Consignee Refused To Accept</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="reason_code_description">Consignee Refused To Accept</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="reason_code_number">221 </field>
    <field type="CharField" name="receiver"></field>
    <field type="CharField" name="expected_date" >15-Feb-2014</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="last_update_date" ></field>
    <field type="CharField" name="delivery_date" ></field>
    <field type="CharField" name="ref_awb" >703063993</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="rts_shipment" >0</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="system_delivery_update" ></field>
    <field type="CharField" name="rts_system_delivery_status" Undelivered</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="rts_reason_code_number">777</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="rts_last_update">22 Jan, 2014, 12:44 </field>
    <field type="CharField" name="pincode" >400037</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="city" >MUMBAI</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="state" >Maharashtra</field>
    <field name="scans">
</ecomexpress-objects>
```

If i try the following code to parse

```
    String xml=result.toString();
    try{
       DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is;
        is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        NodeList nodelist = doc.getChildNodes();
       }
      catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the following error.

```
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: expected: /field read: ecomexpress-objects (position:END_TAG </ecomexpress-objects>@1:1917 in java.io.StringReader@39978dff)
```

I need to store all field values in respective string variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your xml :

- No closing tag `object` .
- `Undelivered` appears in attribute at : `<field type="CharField"

  name="rts_system_delivery_status" Undelivered</field>`
- should be closed like `<field name="scans"/>`

As long as xml is invalid, you keep getting exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not valid.

The tag `<field name="scans">` is not closed.

Comment: This is the response from third party API. I have no control over it

Comment: @Sumi you can not use an XML Parser to parse an corrupted XML. Talk to the Provider that the issue will be fixed